# How to get URL for Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components

I have a Lightning component that deletes records as a URL button on a related list. I'm trying to find out how to get the URL for the Lightning component to call it to delete the related list records. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

For *Aura component*s, you have [isURLAddressable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:isUrlAddressable/documentation) which you can implement. Example code is taken from the documentation

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable" description="c:helloTarget component">
    <aura:attribute name="id" type="String" />
    <!-- Add an "init" handler to handle the first "v.pageReference" value -->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onPageReferenceChange}"/>
    <!-- Add a "change" handler to handle all changes to the "v.pageReference" value -->
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.pageReference}" action="{!c.onPageReferenceChange}"/>
    Hello {!v.id}.
</aura:component>
```

```
({
    onPageReferenceChange: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
        var myPageRef = cmp.get("v.pageReference");
        var id = myPageRef.state.c__id;
        cmp.set("v.id", id);
    }
})
```

Then you can use the following URL to navigate to the component (and even pass in parameters as well)

```
/lightning/cmp/c__helloTarget?c__id=001XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

For Lightning Web Components (LWC), you could:

1. Wrap it in an aura component (and use the info above) if you want to pass parameters
2. Create a LWC tab using your component and then direct the URL to that tab/page